# Is it correct to say "We do better, because we do for you"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Here some context to my question. I'm not a native english speaker and I would like to know if the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> "We do better, because we do for you"

It feels super weird to me. Intuitively I think it should be:

> "We do **it** better, because we do **it** for you"

Can someone tell me if any of this phrases would be grammatically acceptable? More than that I would like to know the gramatical reason why one would be better than other. I think the verb must always have a direct object, but I'm not sure if this is a rule.

Furthermore, people have pointed out that there might be a problem with the meaning of the first sentence. This supposes to be a kind of a slogan, the meaning is as important as the grammar.

Comment: I would say *We do better, because we **work** for you.* As a slogan, the repeated pronoun doesn't sound quite as natural. Of course, it could simply be *We do it better for you.*

Comment: Definitely change 'we do for you'. In informal British English, to 'do for' someone means to kill them.

Comment: Even if you change it, "We do better because we do it for you" doesn't actually mean anything, it's an empty slogan that just "sounds good". I'd be more impressed if a company said "We do better because we have better people and better ideas".

Comment: I did not like the slogan either... My question regards the grammar, though...

Comment: Slogans don't always have to mean much. In France they used to advertise a certain brand of domestic appliances with "C'est bon, c'est beau, c'est Bosch".

Comment: @JasonBassford Parallelism and alliteration are important in making slogans catchy. Your alternative isn't nearly as memorable.

Comment: Consider the famous "We're here we're queer, get used to it". Would it have cought on if it were "We here, we're gay, get used to it"?

Comment: Time for the one and only first-place winning vacuum cleaner slogan: "Nothing sucks like an Electrolux".

Comment: Of course there goes the alliteration by adding *an* to *an Electrolux*. Would have been better with "Nothing sucks like Electrolux".

Comment: I've edite the question to focus on the grammar. I would like to know if I must use "it" on the sentence.

Comment: Yes, you must use **it**. In this context "do" is transitive.